# How can I add extra memory in my ram android?

Tags: ram

I want to boost the ram's memory, but as I clean my phone,it's memory was almost full.

Answer (score 0):

You can create swap file on your SD card by using [ROEHSOFT RAM Expander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.swapit.expander.de) or [Swapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.azasoft.free.swapper) (Free) without creating swap partition. Both app require root access. Apps need kernel swap support to work so check if your phone is compatible or not with [MemoryInfo & Swapfile Check](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roehsoft.meminfo) first.